# Recovery of SSH session after system crash

Tags: ssh, crash, recovery, bsod

I was editing a file over SSH when my computer crashed and I got the BSOD. I was SSHing through Putty. I would really like to recover if possible. I don't know if there is anyway to restore the SSH session and save from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the remote computer's operating system? Is it some Linux server? How did you edited the file? With `emacs`, `vi` or what? Did you consider redoing again the `ssh` and restarting the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to restore your session, unless you used something like screen.

But there might be a way to restore your file, but that depends on the editor you used. Editors like Vim and Emacs store the changes of unsaved files, and will notify you the next time you open the file.

Thus all you have to do in this case is open the same file again. In other cases the changes might just be gone.